# Deploy Eclipse Dynamic Web Project To Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse named Project that I'm able to run on my computer using Tomcat and MySQL. I exported the project as a .war file and gave it to Amazon, selected Tomcat as the platform, and Amazon gives me a url that should take me or anybody else with the url to the website.

However, the css doesn't render on any of the pages, and the majority of the pages are not even accessible using the path they're supposed to be accessible from (they throw 404 errors). For example, in my browser, localhost:8080/Project/home takes me to the home page of my app, but ...elasticbeanstalk.com/Project/home throws a 404; even stranger: ...elasticbeanstalk.com/home takes me to my homepage, but without css.

I haven't yet added an Amazon database to my web application so I was expecting some SQLExceptions (which my application catches by displaying a custom database error page), but I don't even get that far.

Can somebody provide some guidance or a link to an in-depth tutorial on how to publish a website using AWS?